# TextView from database not detect in adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, textview, event-listener

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<Result> results;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<Result> results) {
        this.context = context;
        this.results = results;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_view, parent, false);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(v);

        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Result result = results.get(position);
        holder.textViewId.setText(result.getId());
        holder.textViewName.setText(result.getName());
        holder.textViewPhone.setText(result.getPhone());
        holder.textViewAddress.setText(result.getAddress());
        holder.textViewStatus.setText(result.getStatus());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return results.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

        @BindView(R.id.textId) TextView textViewId;
        @BindView(R.id.textName) TextView textViewName;
        @BindView(R.id.textPhone) TextView textViewPhone;
        @BindView(R.id.textAddress) TextView textViewAddress;
        @BindView(R.id.textStatus) TextView textViewStatus;
        @BindView(R.id.button) Button button;
        @BindView(R.id.checkBox) CheckBox checkBox;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

            String status = textViewStatus.getText().toString();
            if(status.equals("Check")){
                checkBox.setChecked(true);
            }else{
                checkBox.setChecked(false);
            }
        }
```

I've retrieved the data from MySQL database to the `text view` in `recyclerview` show name status phone..., the status will show check and not check, I added checkbox in the adapter to set the checkbox check if the `textview` status is check, but the string status compare it to the `textview` value `android:text` in XML not the value from database, it can only detect the value from database if I add listener... how can i do it without `onClick` listener?

Comment: What you actually want ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not place this block of code in the `onBindViewHolder` method instead:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ...
    String status = holder.textViewStatus.getText().toString();
    if(status.equals("Check")){
       holder.checkBox.setChecked(true);
    }else{
       holder.checkBox.setChecked(false);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you get Text from TextView in a constructor of Viewholder which is called before your onBindViewHolder() in which you set Text in TextView and also constructor called only one time after creating RecyclerView.
So, Please add this code in onBindViewHolder() method to get the correct response.

```
String status = textViewStatus.getText().toString();
            if(status.equals("Check")){
                checkBox.setChecked(true);
            }else{
                checkBox.setChecked(false);
            }
```